# a SQL query for codeigniter project

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

In my codeigniter project, User enter course code and regional center by using drop downs. According to this both data, system should calculate total income of the last 3 years for relevant course code AND regional center.

As an example,
In “**budget**” table, course code-**ABC1123** and **Perth** regional center has 4 data. The system should find the latest **3 years of income** for the "Sum of income" column. The course code and regional center are selected by user.

Could you please tell me the **SQL query** for the above mentioned statement using **CodeIgniter**?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(income)
from budget
where code = ? and center = ?
and year > (
    select max(year) - 3
    from budget
    where code = ? and center = ?
)
```

The inner query gets the latest year for code & center and then subtracts 3. And the outer query then sums up all incomes for code & center for years that are greater than this calculated year, so for the last 3 years.

For CodeIgniter3 this would be:

```
$this->db->query(
'select sum(income)
from budget
where code = ? and center = ?
and year > (
    select max(year) - 3
    from budget
    where code = ? and center = ?
)', array($code, $center, $code, $center)); // ->row() or ->row_array()
```

And for CodeIgniter4 use `$db->query(...)` instead of `$this->db->query(...)`.